# IntelliJ IDEA: Custom regions folding in xml

Tags: intellij-idea

I found out it is possible to create custom regions folding in java files with nice line comments as descibed here: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/folding-custom-regions-with-line-comments.html but I can see this only works for java files. Is it somehow possible to make it work in xml files like in pom.xml.
What I would like to achieve is to introduce custom regions in dependencies to make it easier to navigate between them.

Comment: If you only need to navigate between dependencies easily then use the file structure window instead. Alt+F1 then 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML and HTML custom folding regions will be a new feature introduced in upcoming IDEA 2016.3 release (see [IDEA-93649](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-93649)).

If you want to use these features now, you can download the [IDEA 2016.3 EAP release](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/08/intellij-idea-2016-3-eap-is-open) now.

Comment: Great cant wait to use it. Cheers

Answer (score 8):

You can create regions in `XML` like this:

```
<!-- region This will show when folded -->

Your XML goes here.

<!-- endregion -->
```